# how do i update progressbar in ObjectListView or XPTable?

Tags: c#, listview, progress-bar, objectlistview

i was searching for a listview that can embed some controls like progressbar and i found

[ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView)

[XPTable](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11596/XPTable-NET-ListView-meets-Java-s-JTable)

but im so confused about on which tool should i use for my application .. both of them are different but it seems that XPTable is simple more than ObjectListView

i choice XPTable but i can't figure out how to update the progressbar . i've read all of the tutorial .. and searched the samples.. there's nothing about updating that progressbar.
help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've figured out the solution

```
public void UpdateProgressBar(int value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<int>(UpdateProgressBar), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        table1.TableModel.Rows[0].Cells[1].Data = value;
    }
```